# How to use J2ME sdk 3.0 with command line

Tags: java-me

i'm trying to create J2ME app with J2ME sdk 3.0 with command line and i'm confused on how to compile and preverify my source code.can anyone show me how to please ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is blocking you exactly? Try not to ask questions that are too broad.

Comment: ok, i only can write a simple hello world app code and i don't know how to compile and preverify my code.can you give me an example how to do that on command line.i'm using j2me sdk 3.0.5

Comment: Depends on your setup. If you are using something like maven, then you do mvn install . If you are in an IDE, you can run from there. Search around the Internet, you'll find it for your specific setup (I don't know about j2me, sorry).

Comment: you are right it's better to use IDE.thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I'll add this as a response so you can tick it and close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much all IDE's allow you to run and compile the code inside them, rather than having a separate pipeline to edit the text files, compile them and run them.

For example, in IDEA you have a "Run" menu that you can use to access all those functionalities.

I suggest that, especially if you are inexperienced, you switch from a "manual" process using separate tools (text editor, compiler, runner) to a more unified one, that will sort out most of the details for you letting you focus on the writing of the code / logic.